# type of unicode never changes even after typecasting python

Tags: python, string, unicode

Does anyone know why the type of a unicode string never changes even after typecasting. This is in Python and I have a sample that I tried out -similar to what is going on in my script.

I need to check if 2 variables (ints) should be equal. One of them is an int but the other one, even after using int/float types the type never changes from unicode.

```
>>> x = 999.99
>>> type(x)
<type 'float'>
>>> x = u'999.99'
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> x.decode('utf-8')
u'999.99'
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> float(x)
999.99
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> int(float(x))
999
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`float(x)` doesn't actually modify `x`, it just returns a `float`-casted copy of it. I guess what you want is:

```
x = int(float(x))
```